# Lighttpd can not start when including mod_rewrite

Tags: web-server, mod-rewrite, freebsd, lighttpd

Here is my server modules list (`modules.conf`), its working without any problems, and lighttpd is running correctly while using this list:

```
server.modules = (
  "mod_access",
#  "mod_alias",
#  "mod_auth",
#  "mod_evasive",
#  "mod_redirect",
#  "mod_rewrite",
#  "mod_setenv",
#  "mod_usertrack",
)
```

The problem appears, when I want to uncomment the `mod_rewrite` module:

```
server.modules = (
  "mod_access",
#  "mod_alias",
#  "mod_auth",
#  "mod_evasive",
#  "mod_redirect",
   "mod_rewrite",
#  "mod_setenv",
#  "mod_usertrack",
)
```

Then I'm getting the following message, when I want to run my web server:

> 2012-05-01 15:01:18: (plugin.c.169) dlopen() failed for:
>   /usr/local/lib/lighttpd/mod_indexfile, mod_access.so Cannot open
>   "/usr/local/lib/lighttpd/mod_indexfile, mod_access.so"
>
> 2012-05-01 15:01:18: (server.c.656) loading plugins finally failed
>   /usr/local/etc/rc.d/lighttpd: WARNING: failed to start lighttpd

As you can see, it does have some problems with the `mod_access` module, but its strange a little bit, especially when I comment back the `mod_rewrite` module then its working.

Where is the problem?

Comment: Please don't [cross-post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10398141/lighttpd-can-not-start-when-including-mod-rewrite).  Can you provide your entire config?

Comment: @ShaneMadden Here, http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=ze3LsifH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$HTTP["host"] =~ "(^|\.)mywebsite\.com$" {
    server.modules += ( "mod_rewrite" )
```

That's the problem.  Don't modify `server.modules` within a conditional block.  See [here](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/issues/1673).

Comment: Then what I have to do? And how comes this one `server.modules += ( "mod_fastcgi" )` at the bottom is working correctly?

Comment: Move it outside of the `$HTTP["host"]` block.  The `mod_fastcgi` append works because it's not in a conditional block.

Comment: Oh, well.. I'd never though something like this may happend.. that really doesn't make any difference at all. But I'm happy its finally working. Thank you.

Comment: @Cyclone Yeah, that's an absolutely unhelpful error message that it gives in this case.  Glad it's working now!